# django url variable to get parameters

Tags: django, django-urls

I've a part of my urls.py file as follow:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', DetailHomePublic),
    url(r'^demo/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='public/demo.html')),
    url(r'^privacy/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='public/privacy.html')),
    url(r'^terms/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='public/terms.html')),
    url(r'^login/$', Login),
    url(r'^logout/$', Logout),
    url(r'^lost_password/$', LostPassword),
    url(r'^register/$', Register),
)
```

I've done a middleware which catch if a parameters named language is passed. It's used to change the language of the website.

```
class SetLanguageMiddleware:
"""
Middleware which changes the language if the GET variable named language has been set with a valid language referenced on the settings.py file
"""
def process_request(self, request):
    from django.utils import translation
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.utils.translation import LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY



    if 'language' in request.GET:
        language = request.GET['language']
        #check if the language is defined in the settings.LANGUAGES global settings

        if any(language in code for code in settings.LANGUAGES):
            #set the given language in the session and active it for the current page too
            request.session[LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = language
            translation.activate(request.session[LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY])
```

Now, for only this given page, I'd like to add a language prefix to provide a multilingual website.

Is it possible to catach the prefix on the urls file and add it to the GET parameters, to have something like that:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<language>[a-z]{3})$', DetailHomePublic),
    url(r'^(?P<language>[a-z]{3})demo/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='public/demo.html')),
)
...
```

Thank you

Comment: Yes it is possible. And what you've already written, will work. But they will be available as params in your views. But I don't exactly understand what you don't know, or can't figure out.

Comment: The issue it's that if I do like it's shown in my exemple on the url like that : url(r'^(?P<language>[a-z]{3})$', DetailHomePublic) the DetailHomePublic needs to be set to retrieve this argument. Or, I don't want this variable to be the argument of this view, but just catch by my middleware. Is it more clear?

Comment: I've dig a bit into my issue and find a workaround by doing a rewrite on the nginx configuration, but it looks a bit dirty to do it, should it better to do it on the urls file? If so, what would be the equivalent on the django way to replace this line **rewrite "^/([a-z]{2})(/.*)$" /$2?language=$1;**